# In "proof of concept" is the concept proved or proofed?

Tags: verbs

That is, after a successful proof of concept would you say "the concept was proved" or "the concept was successfully proofed".

I'm thinking the latter based on the definition of *to proof* as "to test; examine for flaws, errors, etc." and because *proved* implies a higher standard (truth); however, *proved* (or *proven*) sounds better and *to prove* has a similarly applicable alternate definition: "to give demonstration of by action."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly true that a "proof of concept" will not necessarily prove the concept. The test may fail. But that fact is hardly unique to this particular use of the word "proof". If you say, "I am looking for proof that the Polynesians discovered America", you may or may not find such proof. Etc etc.

When a proof of concept test is completed, if it was successful the concept is "proven" or "proved". If the proof of concept test failed, then the idea is either "disproven" -- we proved that it doesn't work -- or "unproven" -- the results were not adequate to say it whether it will work or not.

"Proof" as a verb is generally understood to refer to examination of text for errors, as in "The editor proofed the manuscript." I don't think I've ever heard someone say, "The engineer proofed the airplane's wings" or "The accountants proofed the tax software". Certainly not, "The physicist proofed his cold fusion theory." The verb "proof" has very little to do with the noun "proof".

Comment: I believe that in usages such as "The editor proofed the manuscript", *proofed* is shorthand for *proofread*.

Comment: "The engineer proofed the airplane's wings" sounds to me as if he's applying some sort of protective coating.

Comment: Thanks. Of all the fine answers, this is the most convincing.

Comment: @Martha: Maybe so. I'm not aware of any difference in meaning between "proofing a manuscript" and "proofreading a manuscript".

Comment: -1 'proof of concept' cannot be broken without losing the significant implication of the integral term.

Comment: @Kris: What do you mean? How is a proof of concept "broken"? What do you mean by the "integral term"?

Comment: Pl see the answer by Cindi below re: integral term (standalone phrase).

Comment: @Kris: It's certainly true that there are some phrases whose meaning is only indirectly related to their constituent parts. But while "proof of concept" is a stock phrase that has a specific meaning beyond simply "proving" a "concept", I think it is nevertheless quite reasonable to talk about whether or not we "proved" it when we're done, and to discuss what the "concept" was that we were trying to prove. Like, "We attempted a proof of concept of our cold fusion generator. blah blah blah And so we conclude that cold fusion has been proven to be a viable method of producing energy."

Comment: I would word it more pragmatically: 'Now that we **have** the proof of concept ...', rather than 'Now that we have proved the concept'. That would still be a carry-forward from the technical into the literary (not recommended). When we are into plain-speaking, it's plain-speaking, avoiding all jargon.

Answer (score 5):

When you have demonstrated a successful proof of a concept, it has been **proved**. After all, one of the definitions of **prove** is *demonstrate the truth or existence of (something) by evidence or argument*, as in *the concept is difficult to prove*.

Answer (score 4):

Prove-as-in-test really only survives in stock phrases such as *the exception that proves the rule* : [proof of concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) seems too recent to have that meaning.

It's really a fixed, standalone phrase now, so I would avoid inflecting it : I'd just say a successful proof of concept has been completed.

Comment: I agree with the first part but for the second, I don't see a difference from *proof of identity* and we do say things like *prove your identity*.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of a proof of concept is not so much to test or examine an idea or technique for flaws as it is to persuade by demonstration that an idea or technique is useful.[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) So, given the choice, "**prove**" is better.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO would describe the end game of a proof of [a] concept as a *proven* or *disproved* concept.

A proofed concept sounds like a concept which has received some previous justification and is not a concept under test; a dogma

Comment: He proved. 
It has been proven.